# How to disable hide/unhide in WPF Ribbon Control

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

I am using the latest Ribbon Control from MS. When one double click the Tab Header, the whole Ribbon will hide the content and show only the header text. I want to disable this hide/unhide feature. So even if user double click Tab Header, the Ribbon remain as it is.

I think it should be the `OnMouseDoubleClick` Event in [RibbonTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbontab.aspx) but have no clue how to override it. Am I suppose to give it a x:Name to each and every RibbonTab then write an empty method `ribbonTab1_OnMouseDoubleClick` to each Ribbon Tab?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the PreviewMouseDoubleClick event in the [Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.aspx):

```
PreviewMouseDoubleClick="ribbon_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"
```

and then in the handler, mark the event as handled:

```
private void ribbon_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```